# phalcon MVC model how can delete data?

Tags: php, phalcon

[image: delAction]

I am searching for a long time on net, but no luck. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I want to delete some data like:

```
$articleIds = '1,2,3,5,8';
$User    = new User();
$success = $User->delete($articleIds);
```

But, that gives an error. What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.phalconphp.com/zh/3.2/db-layer

Comment: thanks ur help ,so much!

Comment: If your question was solved, please consider mark the @YOMorales answer as it.

Answer (score 3):

Try any of the following ways of deleting multiple records, and pick the one you like the best:

A) Finding then deleting:

```
$ids = '1,2,3';
$records = User::find(sprintf("id IN (%s)", $ids)); // or you can avoid using sprintf and simply use concatenating operator like "IN (" . $ids . ")"
$records->delete(); // this should return boolean
```

B) You can also chain the above method calls:

```
User::find(sprintf("id IN (%s)", $ids))->delete();
```

C) Or you can iterate each record and then delete it, like shown in the Phalcon documentation: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/db-models#delete-records

D) Or finally, you can write a 'raw' SQL statement using Phalcon PHQL:

```
$config = [
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'dbname' => 'test'
];
$connection = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql($config);
$sql = sprintf("DELETE `users` WHERE `id` IN (%s)", $ids);
$success = $connection->execute($sql);
```

More info here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/db-layer#crud

---

And remember... be very very careful with accepting record ids from user input (examples: via GET, or from a form/table that allows the user to select records). But I think this is a topic for another question.

Answer (score 0):

First sanitize your input and make sure that only `int` variables are accepted into your array of ids. After that use the following code and delete all your records.

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3];
$records = User::find([
    'conditions' => 'id IN (:ids:)',
    'bind' => array('ids' => implode(', ', $ids)),
]);
$records->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$models = VoucherThemeModel::find([
  'conditions' => 'voucher_theme_id IN ({ids:array})',
  'bind' => ['ids' => $voucher_ids]
]);

$models->delete();
```